# Return highest number from distinct date

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Data:

```
Name | Score | Date
==
John | 10 | 09/01/2012
John | 20 | 09/01/2012
John | 5 | 09/01/2012
Frank | 20 | 11/01/2012
```

I want to run an SQL statement that will pull only the highest score from each day only, so I don't want three scores from one date, only the highest. So the return I'd like from SQL would be:

```
John  | 20 | 09/01/2012    
Frank | 20 | 11/01/2012
```

Is it possible to do this via SQL, currently I can do it after pulling everything by checking dates. But would be great if it's possible to do it direct from the DB.

I have tried a few solutions but as Date and Score aren't distinct, as I want the highest I am unsure of where to proceed. The SQL is being used with a MS Access database.

Comment: There is an ambiguity here. If the data for 09/01/2012 was for three different names, what do you want to be returned? The Date, high score for that date, and the name that matches that high score? Also, what if two different names both have the same highest score on the same date?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Both solutions should work.

Comment: With the edits, they have different behaviours as you have not specified what *should* happen if two different people have scores in the same day, and/or if they are tied for the highest score.

Comment: @Dems fair point. It would be the highest record per date. But I see your point about 2 with the same score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete example. I did it in Oracle, so you might have to tweak the syntax a bit for Access.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (NAME VARCHAR2(100), score INT, Dt DATE);

INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('John',10,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('John',20,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('John',5,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('Harry',15,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('Frank',20,to_date('20121101','YYYYMMDD'));


select a.dt
     , b.name
     , a.score
  FROM (SELECT dt
             , MAX(score) score
          FROM tbl1
       GROUP BY dt) a
     , (SELECT NAME
             , dt
             , MAX(score) score
          FROM tbl1
       GROUP BY name, dt) b
  WHERE a.dt = b.dt
    AND a.score = b.score
```

**Output:**

```
1   11/1/2012   Frank   20
2   9/1/2012    John    20
```

Note that if two people have highest score for given day, it will print them both. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('John',10,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('John',20,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('John',5,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('Harry',20,to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('Frank',20,to_date('20121101','YYYYMMDD'));


select a.dt
     , b.name
     , a.score
  FROM (SELECT dt
             , MAX(score) score
          FROM tbl1
       GROUP BY dt) a
     , (SELECT NAME
             , dt
             , MAX(score) score
          FROM tbl1
       GROUP BY name, dt) b
  WHERE a.dt = b.dt
    AND a.score = b.score
```

**Output:**

```
    DT          NAME    SCORE
1   11/1/2012   Frank   20
2   9/1/2012    John    20
3   9/1/2012    Harry   20
```

Comment: +0 : Your second answer seems closest to what the OP described in English. The example output, however, also included the name associated to the highest score that day.  You do not include that name.

Comment: @Dems - Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm working on revised answer.

Comment: @Dems - Please check revised answer and let me know what you think thanks.

Comment: The second sub-query could just be `tbl1`, the join will ensure that you only get one score per day. But, yes, this works, as far as i understand the OP's question. *[Although, I only upvote answers that use ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, rather than `,`'s, sorry.]*

Comment: That's a better solution so. So it can have a tie and more than one high score. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is pretty simple

```
Select [Name], max([score]) as Score, [Date] from scoresTable
   group by [Date], [Name]
```

### Edited:

More accurate but a little complex

```
select o.[Name], i.[Date], i.Score from scoresTable o
inner join (select [Date], max(Score) as Score
   from scoresTable group by [Date]) as i
on o.[Date] = i.[Date] and i.Score = o.Score
```

Even More, if your date field contains time too

```
select o.[Name], i.[Date], i.Score from scoresTable o
inner join (select convert(varchar, [Date], 101) as Date, max(Score) as Score
  from scoresTable
    group by convert(varchar, [Date], 101)) as i
on convert(varchar, o.[Date], 101) = i.[Date] and i.Score = o.Score
```

Comment: There is an assumption here, and it does ***not*** match what the OP wrote in English.  That is, the OP only ever wants one record per Date, and this return one record per Name per Date.  *[If the data for 09/01/2012 was for three different people, only one record should be returned, you return 3.]*

Comment: `I want to run an SQL statement that will pull only the highest score from each day only, so I don't want three scores from one date, only the highest.` That is clear to me that the OP wants one record per day. The example output includes a name field, but I interpret that as being the name associated with the highest score, else it would conflict with the quote above. Also, if you answer a question that your feel is unlcear, then you should specify the assumptions you are working with.

Comment: The Alias, forgot all about that. Thank you.

Comment: @Dems - "That is clear to me that the OP wants one record per day" You're forgetting the case where 2 (or more) names have highest score per given day (see my answer for details and an example). I did specify that assumption in my answer, by the way :).

Comment: Why convert the date to a string?  It will degrade the performance of the JOIN as it won't be able to make use of an index seek.  *[If the date needs formatting, do that in the client, or the outer query if you must, but not the inner query; for performance reasons.]*

Comment: @Dems if you are saving time with the date then you need to get only date part and do the group by on that.